# How to format React Project in VSCode with ESLint, Prettier, and Flow ending tag without {" "}

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, flowtype, prettier

I am new to web development, and I have never seen tags closed by {" "}. Why is that?

I have a React project created with the Create React App: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app

I have my project set up with ESLint, Prettier, and Flow using VSCode as my editor. I followed this when setting up my project: https://medium.com/js-imaginea/setup-eslint-prettier-and-flow-in-vscode-a3fd6a48b70a

Here are my VSCode Extensions:

- Beautify
- Editor Config for VS Code
- ESLint
- Flow Language Support
- Prettier - Code formatter

Here is my .eslint.json:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1
  }
}
```

Here is my VSCode Settings:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "line",
  "terminal.integrated.enableBell": true,
  "dart.flutterCreateIOSLanguage": "swift",
  "dart.flutterCreateAndroidLanguage": "kotlin",
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
  "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/bash",
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.classpath": true,
    "**/.project": true,
    "**/.settings": true,
    "**/.factorypath": true
  },
  "files.autoSave": "off",
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": true,
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
}
```

Normally, I thought elements were closed like so:

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

But, something happening with ESLint, Prettier, and/or Flow that's formatting it like this (on save):

```
<h1> Hello World! </h1>{" "}
```

I don't know what the

```
{" "}
```

is. It also adds spaces around the string inside. Is this the right way of formatting?  If not, how do I go about removing it? Whenever I save my project, it adds that to the end of an element.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is fixed,

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

and

```
"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
```

in my VS Code settings seemed to be conflicting. Changing my VS Code settings to the following:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
```

seems to fix the issue. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are leaving trailing space at the end and eslint/priettier makes it more visible to let everyone know it is your real intention to place space there.

It might look unnecessary at first but there is real difference sometimes in HTML outcome.

Comment: Actually, when I save the file like this:
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

It automatically formats it like this:
<h1> Hello World! </h1>{" "}

Comment: Can you list me your prettier/eslint version? Are you sure you are not leaving trailing space?

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "flow-bin": "^0.96.0",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4"
  }

and I am sure that I am not leaving any trailing spaces.